# How to show $G(p)$ is a subgroup of $G$ an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> If $G$ is an abelian group and $p$ is a prime then
>   $$G(p):=\{g \in G: \mathrm{ord}(g)=p^n, n \geq 0\} \leq G.$$

I think I may be making this problem too difficult. I know $G(p)\neq \varnothing$ as $\mathrm{ord}(e)=p^0$ so $e \in G(p)$.

If $a,b \in G(p)$ then say $\mathrm{ord}(a)=p^n$ and $\mathrm{ord}(b)=p^m$. Then, if $M=\max\{n,m\}$ then $\mathrm{ord}(ab)=p^M$, is my claim. It is easy to show that $(ab)^{p^M}=e$. I suppose what I am trying to show, if it is possible, if this is a way to go about this at least is
$$a^xb^x=e \Rightarrow a^x=b^x=e \qquad\text{ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$} \qquad \text{(1)}$$
as if I can do this then if I suppose I have some $j<M$ with $(ab)^j=e$ then I will have a contradiction since $j$ will be smaller than whichever of the $m,n$ is the max, contradicting that particular $m,n$ being the smallest positive integer with $a^n=e$, for example. Any tips on how to prove $(1)$ if it is true? lol Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you mean $(ab)^{p^M}=e$.

Comment: Thank you, made the change, my mistake heh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your claim is false, as $a^x$ might be the inverse of $b^x$.
In fact, you are making this too complicated: just show that, if $(ab)^n=e$, then $\text{ord}(ab)\mid n$. As $(ab)^{p^M}=e$, it tells us that $\text{ord}(ab)$ is a $p$-power as well. Hence $G(p)$ is multiplicatively closed. Since, if $\text{ord}(a)=p^n$, then $\text{ord}(a^{-1})=p^n$ as well, we conclude that $G(p)$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You are trying to prove too much.  (And, in fact, your claim is not true!)  Remember: if $a^m=1$, then the order of $a$ must divide $m$. Not many things can divide $p^n$.

Comment: Indeed, I felt like I was over thinking things okay, thank you!